# Getting an error on class instantiation

Tags: java

new Java user here. Need help with the class assignment.
What does this code do? And why am i getting an error on Stack s = new Stack(10); and s.top() methods.

```
public class StackExample 
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Stack s = new Stack(10);

        System.out.println("Adding 33 and 47 to stack.");
        // push adds the item to the top of the stack
        s.push(33);
        s.push(47);  

        System.out.println("Top of stack: " + s.top());
        System.out.println("Items in stack: " + s.size());

        // pop removes the top item
        System.out.println("Removing top item.");
        s.pop();     

        System.out.println("Top of stack: " + s.top());
        System.out.println("Items in stack: " + s.size());
        System.out.println("Adding a new item.");
        s.push(3);
        System.out.println("Top of stack: " + s.top());
        System.out.println("Items in stack: " + s.size());
     }
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Try `s.peek()` instead of `s.top()`

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what error is it and what is the stack class

Comment: As you are new Java guy here is one tip: whenever you get an error and yo uwant us to help you you need to add relevant part of the error stack trace here. If you are not sure about 'relevant' add all of it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Although your question merits some attention, I would suggest that you take a look at this [checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and see if you can provide some more insights/details into the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

There is no constructor that accepts a size.

There is no `top` method. To see the item without retrieving it, use `peek`. Otherwise `pop`.

This should work.

```
public class StackExample 
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        Stack s = new Stack();

        System.out.println("Adding 33 and 47 to stack.");
        // push adds the item to the top of the stack
        s.push(33);
        s.push(47);  

        System.out.println("Top of stack: " + s.peek());
        System.out.println("Items in stack: " + s.size());

        // pop removes the top item
        System.out.println("Removing top item.");
        s.pop();     

        System.out.println("Top of stack: " + s.peek());
        System.out.println("Items in stack: " + s.size());
        System.out.println("Adding a new item.");
        s.push(3);
        System.out.println("Top of stack: " + s.peek());
        System.out.println("Items in stack: " + s.size());
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `pop` instead of `poll`?

Comment: @lnwvr Yeah :) Fixed it